# 2 switch box powering multiple lights through it

Tags: electrical, wiring

So I have a 2 switch box I am changing the switches to smart, there is one line in, but when it is connected to both switches it trips the breaker, when connected to 1 switch it works fine, when only connected to the one switch there are a few other lights in the house that stop working as well. Not sure how to go about wiring it but would appreciate some help. One switch is a 3 way with another in my kitchen[image]

Comment: When you say "there is one line in" what do you mean by that?  One cable with two wires (black-white)?  One such cable per switch?  How was it wired before, were any white wires on the old switches?

Comment: There is one wire with black white and ground that has power coming into the box

Comment: And no neutrals on the old switches, they were capped in the back of the box. I added the neutral wire from the switches to the bunch in the back

Comment: Please (a) upload pictures showing the various cables, wires and switches and (b) tell us the model # of the new switches.

Comment: Got a photo uploaded, they are labeled, the black and red on the right are hooked to another switch in my kitchen and supply power to a hallway and laundry room. The two labeled lights are the lights in my kitchen that the switches here control. The switches have a ground, neutral(white), and 2 blacks ( all are wires coming out of the back)

Comment: What make and model of smart-switch are you using?  Also, can you post photos of the wiring at the other switch for that matter?

Comment: What brand and model are the new light switches? Is one of them designed to be a 3-way switch and you're planning on it controlling the hallway/laundry lights, if so list both switches

Comment: I don't understand why I see two "light" lines *and also* 3-way circuit. Also, are you *sure* the white wire from the 3-way circuit went to the neutral bundle *before*?    The fact that you have several dead outlets makes me think one of the "light" lines is actually supply hot onward to those outlets.